# OpenMP race condition (Fortran 77 w/ COMMON block)

Tags: fortran, openmp, race-condition, fortran77, inspector

I am trying to parallelise some legacy Fortran code with OpenMP.
Checking for race conditions with Intel Inspector, I have come across a problem in the following code (simplified, tested example):

```
        PROGRAM TEST

!$      use omp_lib
        implicit none
        DOUBLE PRECISION :: x,y,z
        COMMON /firstcomm/ x,y,z
!$OMP THREADPRIVATE(/firstcomm/)

        INTEGER :: i
!$      call omp_set_num_threads(3)       

!$OMP PARALLEL DO
!$OMP+ COPYIN(/firstcomm/)
!$OMP+ PRIVATE(i)
        do i=1,3000
            z = 3.D0
            y = z+log10(z)
            x=y+z
        enddo
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO

        END PROGRAM TEST
```

Intel Inspector detects a race condition between the following lines:

- `!$OMP PARALLEL DO` (read)
- `z = 3.D0` (write)

The Inspector "Disassembly" view offers the following about the two lines, respectively (I do not understand much about these, apart from the fact that the memory addresses in both lines seem to be different):

- `0x3286   callq  0x2a30 <memcpy>`
- `0x3338   movq  %r14, 0x10(%r12)`

As in my main application, the problem occurs for one (/some) variable in the common block, but not for others that are treated in what appears to be the same way.

Can anyone spot my mistake, or is this race condition a false positive?

I am aware that the use of COMMON blocks, in general, is discouraged, but I am  not able to change this for the current project.

Comment: Which Fortran compiler are you using?

Comment: Though I am not an OPENMP expert, I will recommend putting the `THREADPRIVATE` clause on the variables `x,y,z` directly instead of putting it on the common block name `firstcomm`. My thinking is that implementations of openmp might not check if a variable is in a `common` bloc, and then generate a false positive warning where it should not be. This is the only problem I can see in your code.

Comment: @HristoIliev I use ifort 16.0.1.

@innoSPG Interesting thought. In my case, I understand that I have to use `!$OMP THREADPRIVATE` on the common block(s), as my real program uses variables in the common block in subroutines called from the parallel region, without passing them as arguments (the example code does not reflect this, my bad), and the extent of `PRIVATE` is lexical only unless passed to functions/subroutines as an argument. Interestingly, trying the `PRIVATE` approach makes my program fail quickly, which suggests that the original code might in fact be correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically speaking, your example code is incorrect since you are using `COPYIN` to initialise threadprivate copies with data from uninitialised `COMMON BLOCK`. But that is not the reason for the data race - adding a `DATA` statement or simply assigning to `x`, `y`, and `z` before the parallel region does not change the outcome.

This is either a (very old) bug in Intel Fortran Compiler, or Intel is interpreting strangely the text of the OpenMP standard ([section 2.15.4.1](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/openmp-4.5.pdf#subsubsection.2.15.4.1) of the current version):

> The copy is done, as if by assignment, *after the team is formed and prior to the start of execution of the associated structured block*.

Intel implements the emphasised text by inserting a `memcpy` at the beginning of the outlined procedure. In other words:

```
!$OMP PARALLEL DO COPYIN(/firstcomm/)
do i = 1, 3000
   ...
end do
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
```

becomes (in a mixture of Fortran and pseudo-code):

```
par_region0:
   my_firstcomm = get_threadprivate_copy(/firstcomm/)
   if (my_firstcomm != firstcomm) then
      memcpy(my_firstcomm, firstcomm, size of firstcomm)
   end if
   // Actual implementation of the DO worksharing construct
   call determine_iterations(1, 3000, low_it, high_it)
   do i = low_it, high_it
     ...
     ... my_firstcomm used here instead of firstcomm
     ...
   end do
   call openmp_barrier
end par_region0

MAIN:
   // Prepare a parallel region with 3 threads
   // and fire the outlined code in the worker threads
   call start_parallel_region(3, par_region0)
   // Fire the outlined code in the master thread
   call par_region0
   call end_parallel_region
```

The outlined procedure first finds the address of the threadprivate copy of the common block, then compares that address to the address of the common block itself. If both addresses match, then the code is being executed in the master thread and no copy is needed, otherwise `memcpy` is called to make a bitwise copy of the master's data into the threadprivate block.

Now, one would expect that there should be a barrier at the end of the initialisation part and right before the start of the loop, and although [Intel employees claim that there is one](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-open-source-openmp-runtime-library/topic/413915#comment-1747417), there is none (tested with ifort 11.0, 14.0, and 16.0). Even more, the Intel Fortran Compiler does not honour the list of variables in the `COPYIN` clause and copies the entire common block if any variable contained in it is listed in the clause, i.e. `COPYIN(x)` is treated the same as `COPYIN(/firstcomm/)`.

Whether those are bugs or features of Intel Fortran Compiler, only Intel could tell. It could also be that I'm misreading the assembly output. **If anyone could find the missing barrier, please let me know.** One possible workaround would be to split the combined directive and insert an explicit barrier before the worksharing construct:

```
!$OMP PARALLEL COPYIN(/firstcomm/) PRIVATE(I)
!$OMP BARRIER
!$OMP DO
      do i = 1, 3000
         z = 3.D0
         y = z+log10(z)
         x = y+z
      end do
!$OMP END DO
!$OMP END PARALLEL
```

With that change, the data race will shift into the initialisation of the internal dispatch table within the `log10` call, which is probably a false positive.

GCC implements `COPYIN` differently. It creates a shared copy of the threadprivate data of the master thread, which copy it then passes on to the worker threads for use in the copy process.

Comment: @SteveLionel  bug/feature ?

Comment: Thank you. The solution you proposed did indeed make the race condition disappear, and a new one (read/write and write/write) appear on `y = z+log10(z)`. Could you perhaps elaborate on why you expected this? How can I verify this data race is a false positive? I actually also detect a seemingly inexplicable data race in a line calling log10 in my main application (which I was trying to recreate in the example, but did not succeed at first).
The Inspector "Disassembly" view of the test program offers exactly the same output for two threads, including memory locations.

Comment: I did not expect it. I was actually anticipating problem-free execution, but then Intel Inspector started detecting the race. I presume, the first call to `log10` triggers detection of the CPU type and selection of the most appropriate version of the function, followed by patching the trampoline used to call the function. The latter is probably what triggers the error. I have reasons to believe that it is done in a thread-safe way and hence the error is a false positive.